# Field Extension $k(t^{1/n})/k(t)$ Cyclic

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, class-field-theory

Let $k$ be a field. We consider the field extension $k(t^{1/n})/k(t)$. My question is why and how to see that it is cyclic, therefore $Gal(k(t^{1/n})/k(t))$ is a cyclic group.

There is one case that is easy:

If we assume that $k(t)$ contains a primitive $n$-th root $\zeta_n$ and futhermore $k(t^{1/n})= k(t)[X]/(X^n-t)$

Kummer thery tells that the extension has indeed cyclic Galois group.

By how to argue if $k(t)$ doesn't contain a primitive $n$-th root? Here Kummer can't help. Any ideas?

Futhermore, what about if we play the same game with the extension $$k((t^{1/n}))/k((t))$$ therefore fractions of $k[[t]]$.

I suppose that this extension has the same Galois group as the extension $k(t^{1/n})/k(t)$ above. Does anybody know how to see it formally/ maybe a theorem providing this result?

Comment: Well, it isn’t normal if the $n$-th roots aren’t in $k(t^{1/n})$, which in most cases means that those roots aren’t in $k$. And unless normal, you can’t even speak of a Galois group.

Comment: @Lubin: So we can us restrict to the first case that $k(t)$ contains a primitive $n$-th root. Then I guess we can again use Kummer for $k((t^{1/n}))= k((t))[X]/(X^n-t)$ to show that it also has cyclic Galois group of degree $n$. Hope, I used Kummer in a correct way

Comment: If $\zeta_n \in k$ then $\sigma(f(t^{1/n})) = f(\zeta_n t^{1/n})$ is an element of $Aut(k(t^{1/n})/k(t))$ and the subfield fixed by $\sigma$ is exactly $k(t)$, whence $k(t^{1/n})/k(t)$ is cyclic with Galois group generated by $\sigma$.

Comment: Your use of Kummer seems right.